# How to output indenting strings in Java?

Tags: java, output, indentation, spaces, towers-of-hanoi

I am doing the Towers of Hanoi and I want to output all the moves (2^n-1) with increasing leading spaces.
E.g.

```
Moving top disk from....
    Moving top disk from....
        Moving top disk from....
            Moving top disk from....
```

... and so on.

I tried to create a separate "space" method, but I'm unsure as to how to implement it into the program

This is a part of my code right now.

```
public static void towersOfHanoi(int disk, int source, int dest){
        int temp;
        if (disk == 1) {
            moveDisk(source,dest);
        }
        else {
            temp = 6 - source - dest;
            towersOfHanoi(disk-1,source,temp);
            moveDisk(source,dest);
            towersOfHanoi(disk-1,temp,dest);
        }
    }
    
    private static void moveDisk(int source, int dest) {
        System.out.println("Moving top disk from " + source + " to " + dest);
    }
```

Comment: Use another parameter for number of level (increase this when needed) and print tab equal number of times of level

Comment: Maybe it's worth to use a `StringBuilder` and `append("\t")` or `append(" ")` depending on the levels.

Comment: You mean adding a parameter in moveDisk? or in towersOfHanoi?

Comment: I'm just mostly unsure as to where do i implement it in the code

Comment: `towersOfHanoi` for level current level and pass level info `moveDisk` for printing

Comment: I did try that, however, because my code is recursive, its a little bit tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a string builder to implement the indents. The number of indents are defined by a static variable for the class "indents" and a for loop is used each time the moveDisk method is called.

```
public class Test {

    static Integer indents = -2;
    static String indent = "   ";
    public static void towersOfHanoi(int disk, int source, int dest){
        int temp;
        if (disk == 1) {
            moveDisk(source,dest);
        }
        else {
            temp = 6 - source - dest;
            towersOfHanoi(disk-1,source,temp);
            moveDisk(source,dest);
            towersOfHanoi(disk-1,temp,dest);
        }
    }

    private static void moveDisk(int source, int dest) {

        indents = indents + 1;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i<=indents; i++){
            sb.append(indent);
        }
        sb.append("Moving top disk from ");
        sb.append(source);
        sb.append( " to ");
        sb.append( dest);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        moveDisk(10, 10);
        moveDisk(1, 10);
        moveDisk(20, 10);

    }
}
```

The outcome:

```
Moving top disk from 10 to 10
   Moving top disk from 1 to 10
      Moving top disk from 20 to 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved it. However, can you further elaborate on how does the "indent" and "indents" work especially on StringBuilder?

Comment: "indent" in this example is just a static string I defined "   " at the top of the class. It can be called anything you like. "indents" is a counter I use. Each time you call the moveDisk method, the counter "indents" will increase by one. I then use a for-loop to append the "indent" to the String by the value of "indents". This way each time the moveDisk method is called, the number of indents added will increase to create the indentation.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you I understand so much better now on how to use the StringBuilder :) Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` via the [Apache Commons Framework.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Then use:

```
StringUtils.leftPad("123456", tab_length * 2) 
//or however you want to format the left space
```

This is the most convenient way, otherwise, you can write a custom leftPad method using StringBuilder or something similar.